# Box-shadow on css and bring texts closer to image

Tags: html, css

I have 4 texts width 8 images. I createds the animation which you can see if copy my code. I need to create four frame with box-shadow for every text, but when I do that my animation doesn`t work correctly. How can do that without losing animation?
I have this css:

```
.div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

:root {
  --time: 24;
}

.div-txt p.label {
  color: #0065de;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
}

.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-txt:nth-child(3) p.label:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-txt:nth-child(3) p.label:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  /*  border: 2px solid #ccc;*/
  /*  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);*/
}

.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 8 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2.66 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.6 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.14 * 1s);
}

.div-txt {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
  1%,
  24% {
    color: #ED5F8A;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  20%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  8%,
  12% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .div-img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

this is html:

```
<div class="div-wrap">
                            <div class="div-txt">
                                <img src="img/svgforlia/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
                                <p class="label" style="margin-top: 15px;">Connect</p>
                                <p>Wear Lia device on the shoulders, <br>turn on it and connect application <br>with device.</p>

                                <img src="img/svgforlia/calibrate.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
                                <p class="label" style="margin-top: 15px;">Calibrate</p>
                                <p>After connection, set up calibration to <br>help device remember your upright <br>and slouch positions.</p>
                            </div>
                              <div class="div-img">
                                <img src="img/mockups/2.png" title="Image 1">
                                <img src="img/mockups/3.png" title="Image 2">
                                <img src="img/mockups/5.png" title="Image 3">
                                <img src="img/mockups/6.png" title="Image 4">
                                <img src="img/mockups/7.png" title="Image 5">
                                <img src="img/mockups/8.png" title="Image 6">
                                <img src="img/mockups/9.png" title="Image 7">
                                <img src="img/mockups/10.png" title="Image 8">
                              </div>
                            <div class="div-txt">
                                <img src="img/svgforlia/train.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
                                <p class="label" style="color: #0065de; margin-top: 10px;">Train</p>
                                <p>Train your posture anytime you want, <br>set up daily goal to improve gradually <br>your posture.</p>
                                <img src="img/svgforlia/analyze.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
                                <p class="label" style="margin-top: 15px;">Analyze</p>
                                <p>Statistics let you track and analyze the <br>progress you’ve made from first <br>training to the last.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Connect needs to change its color firslty, after some second calibrate needs to change its color and all this proccess with other texts while images changes. For 1 text there are 2 images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D I changed my question